# How to import users(csv) to AWS cognito using presignedurl in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, authentication, boto3, amazon-cognito

I am tasked with a mission that i have limited knowledge in. My mission is to get a csv full of user data and import it into aws cognito using boto3 in python. So far i have this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')

response = client.create_user_import_job(
    JobName='TestImport',
    UserPoolId=<My unique string pool id>
    CloudWatchLogsRoleArn= <My unique stringrole arn id>
)
```

This section works and `response` outputs a dictionary which has a key called presignedurl that i am suppose to use to upload the csv into cognitio. I just don't know how to write a python function take that response dictionary and uploads a csv to cognito. Any assist or guidance are appreciated.

Thank you!

For reference i am following this documentation: 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_user_import_jobs

Comment: at a high level use the requests library to do a post of the csv file to the presignedurl it gives you.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @tanenbring yes, i took a different approach, and it worked out

Comment: why you post an answer to close out the question and help out others in the future

Answer (score 5):

Below code snippet helped me to post the csv files successfully to presigned url

```
headers = {'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'aws:kms'}
presigned_url = response['UserImportJob']['PreSignedUrl']
with open(CSV_FILE_NAME, 'rb') as f:
    file_upload_response = requests.put(presigned_url, data=f, headers=headers)
```